# Issue with fixed header and footer when no background is set

Tags: css, fixed, sticky-footer

I have a problem with fixed header and footer implementation.

In this example, when I set a background color for the fixed header and footer, everything works fine.

See here
http://tinyurl.com/brwoeqy

But when there is no background color is set (the background color of the header and footer is the same as the background color of the main body), which is what the client wants, the content area overlaps with the header and the footer.

See here
http://tinyurl.com/cfecdx5

Any solution please??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is working, you just need to set your bg color to #0BB69C on #header_container

Comment: +1 The default background-color is "transparent" so without a background color set, whatever is behind will show through. just set the footer and header to the color you want.